# Is there a season two of Diabolik Lovers?

Tags: diabolik-lovers

How many seasons are there in the *Diabolik Lovers* anime series? Some websites say that there's a season two, and some say that there's only one season.

Comment: The second season is announced, but not aired yet.

Comment: Voting to reopen as this is not about an **unannounced** future event.

Comment: http://www.animenewsnetwork.com/news/2015-02-09/diabolik-lovers-gets-2nd-anime-season-stage-play/.84238

Comment: Are there any updates for this question?

Answer (score 3):

As stated in [the link](http://www.animenewsnetwork.com/news/2015-02-09/diabolik-lovers-gets-2nd-anime-season-stage-play/.84238) that @nhahtdh provided above:

> The official Twitter account for the anime of Rejet's Diabolik Lovers video games for women announced on Monday that a second season of the anime has been green-lit.

The [mentioned Tweet](https://twitter.com/anime_dialover/status/564740026479558656) is as follows (emphasis added):

> **【お知らせ】アニメ「DIABOLIK LOVERS」第２期の制作が決定！ 逆巻兄弟はもちろん、無神兄弟も登場！** 続報をお楽しみに☆
>
> みなさま、応援よろしくお願い致します！！

The bolded text above roughly translates as:

> [Announcement] The second season of the Diabolik Lovers anime has been set! The Sakamaki brothers, of course, and the Mukami brothers as well, will make an appearance.

No airing date nor other details have been announced as of **April 14, 2015**.